# ProFTPD + Debian : list files 19 max

Tags: debian, proftpd

Overnight my ProFTPD server has decided to not list the contents of a folder that has more than 19 files.

I have tried creating more than one folder with exactly the same rights, if the folder has 19 or less files then LIST command works fine. If the folder has twenty or more files nothing shows and I get a timeout. (the size of the files don't make any difference)

I can list all files/folders on a normal web interface (http) so I'm guessing it has something to do with ftp ? I've tried reinstalling ProFTPD and reconfiguring but no change. Users connect correctly to ftp (correct logs).

Thanks for any input guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything server side, I could not do anymore ... Passive ports, marquerade IPs, proftpd .conf files, file rights, chroots

Although none of this did work it gave me the right direction to follow, all ftp listing directory problems seemed to come from ports/firewall issues.

It was finally a firewall issue on the **local** router not on the distant server! why it would block anything above 19 files I still don't know ?